# COUNTIF using excell to count based on 2 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

back again for some excel help.

I am trying to calcuate the total number of #N/A or red cells while also checking if they are a teacher.

It will only count the value when the category is teacher. I have tried using the followng function but cannot count based on both conditions. I can get the count indivdually but not together

[image]

Is there a way in which I can add the second condition to count a color?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C9=G11)*ISERROR(D2:D9))
```

Comment: Thank you. also worked with =COUNTIFS(C2:C8,"Teacher",D2:D8,#N/A)

Comment: yes, I like SUMPRODUCT and #N/A in my version is #N/D, ISERROR works in all XL language. If lock interval=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$8,G2,$D$2:$D$8,#N/A) you can drag formula